# The first position of my array isn't being modified

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, zipcode

I'm creating an application that converts a 5 digit zip code into frame bars. Weirdly, the first digit entered doesn't correctly go through the conversion. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Zip{

    public static String checkDigit(String bar)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] input;
        input = new int [4];
        for(int p = 0; p < 4; p++)
        {
            input[p] = s.nextInt();
            if (input[p] == 0)
            {
                bar = bar + "||:::";
            }
            if (input[p] == 1)
            {
                bar = bar + ":::||";
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        return bar;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {   
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(checkDigit(s.nextLine())); 
    }
}
```

For example, when entering 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 into the array, the output is

"1||:::||:::||:::||:::"

When entering 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 into the array, the output is

"0:::||:::||:::||:::||"

Instead of converting the first digit at pos [0], it just prints the number outright. Why is this?

Comment: Because the initial value of `bar` is retained when you use `bar = bar + ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of `s.nextLine()` it will read the first int entered in console and save it in `String bar` passing into `checkDigit()`

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(checkDigit(s.nextLine()));
```

Pass an empty string

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(checkDigit(""));
```

**Input :** 0 1 1 1

**Output :** ||::::::||:::||:::||

Answer (score 1):

There's not much of a problem here actually @ddalcanto. Your logic is pretty much alright.. Just a few minor mistakes which are causing the anomalies in the output.

1. The 1st input is displayed as it is because you are appending the updated values to the `bar` string which is nothing but the first accepted character because of the `s.nextLine()` in the `main()` function. Hence, see point number 2.
2. There's no need to send the `s.nextLine()` as argument to the function call of `checkDigit()`. Also remove the `string bar` as parameter from the function definition too. This is what is causing you to give an extra input. For example, 5 inputs for intended 4 inputs, etc.
3. Your `input[]` array is of size 4, but you are looping from `0 to 4`, which means 5 times to get 5 inputs, but the array can hold just 4 elemnts. Just change the array size to 5.  =>  `input = new int[5];`

Here is the updated working code along with the associated output.

**CODE:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Zip{

    public static String checkDigit()
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String bar  = "";
        int [] input;
        input = new int [5];
        for(int p = 0; p < 5; p++)
        {
            input[p] = s.nextInt();
            if (input[p] == 0)
            {
                bar = bar + "||:::";
            }
            if (input[p] == 1)
            {
                bar = bar + ":::||";
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        return bar;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {   
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(checkDigit()); 
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ```
>  1
>  1
>  1
>  1
>  1
>
> :::||:::||:::||:::||:::||
> ```

Another input-output pair:

> ```
>  0
>  1
>  1
>  0
>  1
>
> ||::::::||:::||||::::::||
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating and reading from a Scanner object in main() so the first digit goes into the `bar` parameter sent to the `checkDigit` method.

I would remove the bar parameter altogether and also make some other changes.

```
public static String checkDigit() {
    StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = 0;
    for(int p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
        input = s.nextInt();
        if (input == 0) {
            bar.append("||:::");
        }
        if (input == 1) {
            bar.append(":::||");
        }
    }
    return bar.toString();
}
```